# php API daemon process over a url

Tags: php, api, daemon

I need a background process to be an API over a URL.

For example, the url http://www.msite.com/myapi.php will read incoming protocol and reply.

What is the best way to accomplish this scenario?

Should I just treat this as a regular web page?

What are the pros/cons for using a web page url as an API?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this as REST service. Check [this URL](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/) out.

You need to create a proper controller (in case you use MVC approach) and implement proper methods corresponding to your API (HTTP request methods are very important topic here).

Just to illustrate, I allowed myself to paste code from URL I embedded here:

```
GET request to /api/users – List all users
GET request to /api/users/1 – List info for user with ID of 1
POST request to /api/users – Create a new user
PUT request to /api/users/1 – Update user with ID of 1
DELETE request to /api/users/1 – Delete user with ID of 1
```

Just to notice, you can also use different approach like XML-RPC or [SOAP](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap/).